# Problems awking column from txt file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a txt file (input.txt) that looks like this:

```
A_Karitiana-4.DG        Ignore_Karitiana(discovery).DG
A_French-4.DG   Ignore_French(discovery).DG
A_Dinka-4.DG    Dinka.DG
A_Dai-5.DG      Dai.DG
S_Dai-2.DG      Dai.DG
B_Dai-4.DG      Dai.DG
S_Dai-3.DG      Dai.DG
S_Dai-1.DG      Dai.DG
```

I need to create a new txt file (output.txt) that contains only the first column of input.txt. So output.txt must look like this:

```
A_Karitiana-4.DG        
A_French-4.DG   
A_Dinka-4.DG    
A_Dai-5.DG      
S_Dai-2.DG      
B_Dai-4.DG      
S_Dai-3.DG      
S_Dai-1.DG
```

I've tried with this command:

```
awk '$1' input.txt > output.txt
```

and also with this:

```
awk -F' ' '$1' input.txt > output.txt
```

but both of them create an output.txt file that looks exactly the same as input.txt.

I suppose it's a matter of delimiter, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not printing. Try

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt > output.txt
```

When you just give an expression (the way you tried), `awk` works somewhat like default `grep`: completely print any matching lines:

1. `awk '/regexp/' file.txt` - print lines matching regexp
2. `awk 'NR==3' file.txt` - print line 3
3. `awk '1' file.txt` - print all lines where 1 is true, i.e. all (okay, an awk-ward way to cat, but we're approaching what you did)
4. `awk '$1' file.txt` - print all lines where `$1` evaluates to true, i.e. is non-empty (and does not otherwise evaluate to false, such as "0"), i.e. given your file, print all all lines (since `$1` here will always contain a non-numerical, non-empty string)

Answer (score 5):

Awk scripts consist of `pattern {action}` pairs.

- if `pattern` is empty, then `{action}` will be applied to all records
- if `{action}` is empty, then the default action `{print}` will be applied to all records matching `pattern`

`awk '$1'` will apply the default action `{print}` when pattern `$1` evaluates true. Since a non-empty *string* is true, it will print the whole of any non-empty records, except those whose first field evaluates numerically to zero in your locale.

Instead, you want to apply a *non*-default action `{print $1}` to the *default* empty pattern:

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

While this is an `awk` question, I'd nevertheless throw `cut` in here as good alternative for this specific task:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 input.txt > output.txt
```

The default delimiter (tab) has been replaced with space by `-d' '` and the first field selected by `-f1`.